# insert values into table valued parameters in sql server

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am seeing an error when I insert values into user type table. The type created successfully, but I am not able to insert values into that type.

How to insert values into that table type?

```
CREATE TYPE ProductType1 AS TABLE
(
    fld_SkillTargetID int
)
```

I'm trying to insert values into that table type using this statement:

```
declare @par as ProductType1
insert into @par values('fld_SkillTargetID')values(5166)
```

but am getting error. I am not able to insert the values into that table type.

Comment: When saying you get an error, it is a good idea to include the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have one too many `values` - and you don't need to escape the field name:

```
insert into @par (fld_SkillTargetID)
values(5166)
```

Comment: but we cannot insert more than 2000 parameters via tvp. is there a better way to handle